# Add commas to an extracted value

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have a database where I need to store the price of items. Now when I get the values from the database, I would like commas added for the thousand value e.g convert 19000 to 19,000.

```
<?php echo $row['pprice'];?>
```

How can I change the format?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this.

```
echo number_format($row['pprice']);
```

Not sure if its correct but wont hurt to try and see if it works.

Or create a new variable for the `$row['pprice']` so like this.

```
$commaPrice = $row['pprice'];  
echo number_format($commaPrice);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php):

```
$number = 1234.56;
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'it_IT.UTF8');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
```

Note that you need to specify your current locale. If you want to use different locales than yours, you must build them install them on the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

$newNumber = number_format($number);

Comment: Wow never knew there was such a function. Thanks alot guys.it has worked for me